# Magento 2.3 favicon and logo upload does not take hold

Tags: magento2.2.3, logo, favicons

Tired in 2 separate installs of vanilla 2.3 magento commerce.

When trying to update favicon and logo and transnational email logo, the upload spinner will appear but are not saved.

Comment: thanks for your answer. In the link it mentions "app/code/Magento/Theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml" but in my Magento 2.3 there is no code folder in app folder. Also I can't find the file in "vendor" folder. Can you please specify the path to the design_config_form.xml file?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/142612)

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem. I am using Magento ver. 2.3.2 and i referenced the ***vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml*** file and to my surprise i find that the ***Replacement of fileUploader by imageUploader are already applied*** and still cant upload the logo. HELP!!!

Answer (score 14):

File path : /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml

Find and replace :

```
<field name="header_logo_src" formElement="fileUploader">
To
<field name="header_logo_src" formElement="imageUploader">

<field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="fileUploader">
To
<field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="imageUploader">
```

Comment: Works. saved my time.

Answer (score 4):

this is a known bug in 2.3.0, there is already a fix for it in the repo - you can see the fix here which you can apply manually for now.  It will be released in 2.3.1

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/ba69bfec127bed8c39c7d9e7b73d10b54449b158

Comment: same problem in 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

same problem with magento 2.3.1 and the fix it is already added.