# Magento 2.3 : Serving site from pub, now images get 404

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, server-setup, 404

My original installation of v2.3.0 was working fine. All images showed up for categories. I decided (after setting up a lot of categories and images for those categories) to serve the site from `pub`.

The only code customization my site has is [a modification](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/255782/75936) for a [bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/ba69bfec127bed8c39c7d9e7b73d10b54449b158) that is apparently fixed in v2.3.1. Other than that, i have no third party modules installed or other code customizations.

I followed [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html) to make site more secure using Ubuntu and Apache2 (not nginx). When i visit a page with images (front-end or admin area), i get a 404 not found for the image. Page loads text and css but console outputs:

`GET http://192.168.5.10/pub/media/Shoes/nike.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

What i've tried that did not work:

1. Looking for errors in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and  `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (found nothing other than a record of 404 but no permission errors.)
2. Checked `magento/var/log/system.log`, `magento/var/log/exception.log` and `magento/var/log/debug.log`, no permission errors.
3. Switching modes:

   ```
   bin/magento deploy:mode:set production  
   bin/magento cache:flush  
   bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer  
   bin/magento cache:flush
   ```
4. Made sure had default `.htaccess` in `magento` directory.
5. Made sure `pub/` had default `.htaccess`.
6. [Doc:](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cache/static-content-signing.html) `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
7. "Flush Cache Storage", "Flush Magento Cache", "Flush Catalog Images Cache", and "Flush Static Files Cache" from admin area > System > Cache Management.
8. Refresh all cache types from admin area > System > Cache Management.
9. Re-ran [permissions](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html) as root `cd /var/www/html/magento2 && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} + && chown -R :www-data . && chmod u+x bin/magento`
10. Ran alternative [permissions](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/composer.html) commands (does same thing as above):

    ```
    cd /var/www/html/<magento install directory>
    find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
    find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
    chown -R :www-data . # Ubuntu
    chmod u+x bin/magento
    ```
11. Checking permissions of example image from magento directory:

    ```
    magentouser$ ls -al pub/media/Shoes/nike.jpg
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 magentouser www-data 77645 Jan 15 17:14 pub/media/Shoes/nike.jpg
    ```
12. `rm -rf var/cache`
13. `bin/magento indexer:reindex`
14. Checked my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

    ```
    Listen 8080
    <VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2/pub

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    ```
15. Re-started `systemctl restart apache2`
16. Change DocumentRoot back to `/var/www/html/magento2`, and restarted `apache2`.

    Note: i was in the wrong demo server the first time i tried step 16 again. I had spun up so many test servers trying to re-duplicate the issue in different ways (too many terminals open trying to test different variations without attention to IP). I noticed while deleting all the demo servers from the network that the command was in the wrong one. After switching server 56 back to documentRoot to **/var/www/html/magento2**, and restarting `apache` on server 56, all images show up again normally. but the URL is still like (example): `http://192.168.5.10/pub/media/Shoes/nike.jpg`. I'm still not sure how "pub" got in there or even how i would add "pub" if it was't there and I wanted it, or how to remove it from the url and make the system look in the right place without having to re-upload all my images. This test confirmed again that when not serving from `pub`, the site works fine...but images appear to be already served in a strange way (unable to confirm this without a snapshot of the system before following docs to serve from "pub")

    How do you resolve this?

Comment: have you try to restart your server?

Comment: @EdwinWidhiyanto "Have you tried turning it off and back on again" lol. yes

Comment: Hi, @learnsomemore, I am facing same issue, you got solution?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was?

Comment: Yes. The solution was for us was to stop using Magento and develop our own custom solution. For you it might be time to evaluate Magento enterprise (what Adobe wants now that they own it), or look at other open source solutions. Magento has a lot of money invested in marketing. "My site runs on magento -[Some Big Company]" doesn't provide practical insight into if it's a good platform. The quality of code should be most important and if the out of box experience following the docs and combing the repo isn't a clue, the github issues (open and closed) is.

Comment: just for reference, you can overwrite the media URL in the admin settings so you can use a CDN.  Just in case you come across another magento install

Answer (score 2):

Check database table `core_config_data`, rows where path is `web/secure/base_media_url` and `web/secure/base_media_url` if the `value` contains "pub/" in the path. If it does, remove "pub/" from the value.

Answer (score 1):

2 things come to mind based on your description:

1. You might be missing `.htaccess` in your `/pub/media/` folder.
2. Since you made changes to Apache, you might have disabled the `Options` `FollowSymLinks` setting (since you mentioned that you increased security).

So you might have to change

> Options +FollowSymLinks

to

> Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

in `.htaccess` in the following locations:

- {Your root Magento directory}
- /pub/
- /pub/media/

Comment: i made the change to the .htaccess in all 3 areas and restarted apache. Getting a lot more errors (403s in addition to 404s) so i changed it back.

Answer (score 0):

After changing your document root in Apache to point to the pub subdirectory your correct image URL is

```
http://192.168.5.10/media/Shoes/nike.jpg
```

The image URLs provided by Magento should have the correct path, if you have set somewhere 'pub' in your image paths you have to remove that

Comment: I never set images to "pub" anywhere. I uploaded them via the admin GUI while working on categories. I followed the directions exactly from the docs for serving from root. Before serving from pub. images were working. after following docs, images not working.

Comment: ok, can you please provide more information where this image come from? If it is referenced in a cms block, please paste the code in your question. By default magento uploads category images to 'media/catalog/category' directory, images from CMS upload are in 'media/wysiwyg'. Do you get product images with the correct path?

Comment: Images where uploaded before serving from pub. To upload image (in this case, to a category) I went to the category, clicked content, clicked upload. Note from my original...everything worked normally before serving from pub. All i did was change DocumentRoot to serve from pub. I did not upload anything after making serve from pub so if the issue is with default upload directory, it should have showed a problem before serving from pub shouldn't it? Given i haven't uploaded any new images after modifying document root?

Comment: media/Shoes is not a Magento default directory. The default directory for category images uploaded in the content area of the category in the admin panel is media/catalog/category. Have you uploaded the image nike.jpg as "category image" in the admin panel? do you see the image now in the admin panel or at least a broken image there?

Comment: yes, the image is broken in admin area too. "media/Shoes is not a magento default directory". If I create a category in the backend named 'Shoes", and upload a image to the category content area. that image becomes domain/media/<Cagtegory>/<image>.png. or domain/media/Shoes/nike.png

Comment: It seems like you have some customaziation there. The default Magento method for category images `getImageUrl`in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Category` has a hardcoded 'catalog/category' path and can't return such a path. If you have a custom module, try to find out how that's involved and if that stores the custom path when you upload an image. So it might be that you have some pathes with 'pub' in your database

Comment: I do not have any custom modules or custom code implemented beyond manually fixing upload image issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/255782/75936

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have not put name of correct directory of magento installation in virtualhosts, you've to mention path to pub directory of your magento installation in DocumentRoot.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot {path to magento installation}/pub

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory "/var/www/html">
                    AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. it wasn't that. I updated question to reflect test

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was with the permissions of the pub folder. Fixed by giving proper permissions

```
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777 permission for var folder    

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc
```

Answer (score -2):

You just have to remove the trailing slash "/" from the base url. Login to your MySQL console and select the database, execute

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value='http://dev.abc.com' WHERE path='web/unsecure/base_url';
```

At the time of installation Magento by default puts a forward slash at the end of the base url when you change your DocumentRoot to pub, it needs to be updated i.e. remove that trailing slash.