# Magento 2.3 : How to change the logo?

Tags: magento2.3, logo

I want to change luma logo but cannot upload the logo ?

I tried to upload through admin panel. But, Not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change below file

> /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml

change

```
<field name="header_logo_src" formElement="fileUploader">
```

To

```
<field name="header_logo_src" formElement="imageUploader">
```

and change

```
<field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="fileUploader">
```

TO

```
<field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="imageUploader">
```

check this Reference [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252256/magento-2-3-favicon-and-logo-upload-does-not-take-hold)

Comment: thanks for your answer. In the link it mentions "app/code/Magento/Theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml" but in my Magento 2.3 there is no code folder in app folder. Also I can't find the file in "vendor" folder. Can you please specify the path to the design_config_form.xml file?

Comment: This is a bug in 2.3 and patch is available here https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/ba69bfec127bed8c39c7d9e7b73d10b54449b158 . code folder you need to manually add, vendor folder you can find right inside main magento folder

Comment: @sannikalariya you need to run below command after code update
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: also command write

Comment: php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Answer (score 2):

> Goto Content > Configuration > edit your theme >  goto header section
>   upload your logo

Comment: directly not working

Answer (score 1):

Give read write permission on your `pub/media` directory

```
chmod -R 755 pub/media
chown -R www-data:www-data pub/media
```

Then try again

Comment: I also provide permittion @shoaib Munir

Comment: Check @Mitrajsinh answer, `Goto Content > Configuration > edit your theme > goto header section upload your logo`

Answer (score 1):

First run;

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex 
bin/magento setup:di:compile  
bin/magento cache:clean  
bin/magento cache:flush
```

and then replace these settings;

[vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml](http://vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml)

Old 154,

> **field name="header_logo_src" form Element="fileUploader"**

to 
new: 154

> **field name="header_logo_src" formElement="imageUploader"**