# Adding a favicon in magento 2.3.0 manually - it just appears in firefox

Tags: theme, magento2.3.0, favicons

According to **devdocs** of **magento 2.3.0** I tried to add a **favicon** manually.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/favicon.html

**Attempt 1:**

`/magento2/app/design/frontend/Magento GJ/theme-GJ/Magento_Theme/layout`
=> here goes the `default_head_blocks.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Theme::favicon_32x32.png" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="32x32"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

`/magento2/app/design/frontend/Magento GJ/theme-GJ/Magento_Theme/web`
=> here goes the `favicon_32x32.png` file

=> This works only in Firefox!

**Attempt 2:**

Then I tried just for fun to add in the root directory my own `favicon.ico`.

`/magento2/app/design/frontend/Magento GJ/theme-GJ/Magento_Theme/`

=> This works for `Safari`, `Chrome` and `Edge`. The `IE` does not work.

**Attempt 3:**

According to the magento 2.3.0 bug to add a favicon over the backend I solved this issue also:

[Magento 2.3 favicon and logo upload does not take hold](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252256/magento-2-3-favicon-and-logo-upload-does-not-take-hold)

Then I tried to upload my favicon.
=> All browsers can handle the favicon.

I want to know why the first attempt does not work for all browsers? - I am at a loss :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
The .ico file need to be under `<vendor>/<theme>/web/` directory. Without the .ico file the .png images are not working on every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Magento favicon icon with `type="image/x-icon"` should be of file type **`.ico`**, in your case you used a **`.png`** instead and that makes it behave abnormally.
To validate it, try using a **`favicon.ico`** file

Answer (score 0):

After updating to Magento 2.4.6 enterprise edition, in chrome (and only in chrome) the default Adobe favicon was showing instead of the custom one.

I solved by creating `Magento_Enterprise/web/favicon.ico` inside `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>`